# How to use std::type_info in std::pair

Tags: c++, c++17

I need to provide a map that contains vectors of different types. For this std::any is perfect. However it can also happen that a vector is empty and therefore I also need to pass the information about the data type that elements in such empty vector would be. For that I also pass the type_info.

However since this is a constant reference I am not able to manipulate the pair. E.g. as in the last line in the provided code.

```
std::map<std::string, std::pair<std::vector<std::any>, const std:type_info&>> data = {
            {"something",              {{}, typeid(std::string)}},
            {"something2",             {{}, typeid(float)}}
};

data["something"].first.push_back("hello"); // cannot do this here
```

What would be the proper way to achieve this?

**Edit:**
Since it is asked to give some more background information I try to clearify a little bit more:

So the reason I need the type information is that this map is passed forward into another component that does handle a database. This database does need the type information to add columns with the appropiate data format, even when there is no data in the column yet. At some later point the column then might be filled. If it is not filled then the database can retrieve that such a column does exist but it does not have any values yet. Since it is not possible to add a column without specifying the data type as well the user must provide this information.

This also means that for one vector in the map all elements have the same type but different vectors can have different types. So, yes std::any might be overpowered and there might be a better way, which is what I am asking for here.

Comment: You might want to use `variant` instead of `pair`

Comment: You can use a pointer instead

Comment: If the vectors are meant to be homogeneous after creation, then `vector<any>` is a wrong tool with way too much overhead IMO. Just map string -> any, followed by `any_cast<vector<T>>`

Comment: You can even avoid the additional type_info altogether if you don't need nill `any`s. Just always create the vectors (of the concrete type) as empty by default. Then the any_cast is always enough to check.

Comment: The question is rather imprecisely worded, I find.  "I need to provide a map that contains vectors of different types" -> "I need to provide a map that contains vectors of _objects_ of different types", yes?  And you want to be able to determine what type each of those objects are at some future time, presumably.  So why should it matter if the vector is empty?  Or am I missing something?  Perhaps you could clarify, in the question itself, preferably, giving more information about what the goal is.  Beware the dreaded XY problem.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Not sure I can. Your Q seems focused on an issue in your *predetermined* solution to some undisclosed programming problem. As mentioned already, this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/317773) sort of situation. I already made one guess when offering an alternative, so unless you clarify the background problem, I'd just need to guess even more, which is not a fruitful use of anyone's time.

Comment: *...constant reference...*  You can use [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper), or a pointer to the type info.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with this, but appears that [`type_index`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) solves exactly this problem.

Comment: hm, does not seem to solve the issue.

Comment: @Marcel_marcel1991 Please rephrase _"What would be the proper way to achieve this?"_ in a way that makes it easier to answer in a way that leaves no questions.